# python create image shape with effects

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, shadow, effects

I'd like to create an image and giving it some effect so it won't get just a "flat" rectangle.
A shadow or borders could be simulated by drawing other rectangles/lines, but it must be a easy and efficient way to do it!

What function/module can I use in order to add some relief on the rectangle?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

im = Image.new('RGB', (200,50), (100,100,200))
dr = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
im.save("imgRectpng")
```

[image: code Results:]

[image: Desired]

Comment: You could have a look at [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.8/) as interface to imagemagick, which can do [3D-like borders](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#frame) for images.

Comment: That sounds promising! Just not sure how to apply the 3D borders to "my rectangle". thanks